# Data view web part joined subview fails due to extra characters in ID field

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, joined-view

I created a joined subview in a data view web part however it is failing to find any matching items because one of my join columns IdeaID. is bringing in additional characters (see image below).  Unfortunately I can't add another column to my list that contains only the IdeaID value because it will interfere with an SSIS ETL I have in place.  I suspect I need to add some XSLT like `xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(@IdeaID.,';#'),',##0;-,##0')"/>`to trim the IdeaID but I can't seem to hit on the correct line of code in SharePoint Designer.  Anyone know what XSLT needs to be modifed so that my IdeaID will render correctly and successfully find a match?  Thanks in advance!

[image: Value of IdeaID pulled into data view web part]

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand, you should be able to create a variable at the template level and pass that down as a parameter to your join filter. Here's a rough example:

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
 <xsl:variable name="ItemID" select="substring-after(@IdeaID., ';#')" />
```

Personally, I much prefer using the "Related Items" subview than the joined subview, but there are definitely times when joined is better.

If you're calling the page from a link you have control over, you could also set up a query string parameter in the DVWP and pass the ID that way via your link.